# Google maps API projection setting doesn't work when adding maptype as overlay

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Projection setting doesn't work when adding a map through map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0,). But when I add map normally - map.mapTypes.set("Yandex", yandexMapType) projection works OK.

Here is an illustration:
http://jsfiddle.net/uzEmw/

At first I set projection and map:

```
yandexMapType.projection = new YandexProjection();
map.mapTypes.set("Yandex", yandexMapType);
```

map is OK, projection works.

Then I add this map as overlay:

```
map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0,yandexMapType);
```

overlay added without projection transformation.

How can I add an overlayed map with projection transformations?

Answer (score 0):

Guys from Google helped to "solve" my problem:
This is working as intended. Projections on map types are only valid for base map types, not for overlay map types, which must use the same projection as the base map. To set your map type as the base map type:

```
map.mapTypes.set('Yandex', yandexMapType);
map.setMapTypeId('Yandex');
```

So I just can not use overlays with projection on basemap without projection.